# What is the purpose of this jquery library?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I found a library recently for css3 animations and since im a bit new to javascript im not sure what the benefits of it are.

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

It seems to do what jquery on its own can allready do but with css3. So whats the point in using something like this? Except that it seems to normalize vendor prefixes with csshooks...

Or am i missing something?

Comment: CSS3 animations are handled more by the browser and less by javascript, allowing the browser to better optimize the animation usually for better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using native features is always better. That's why jQuery will use `querySelector` if it's available. It will also use JSON if the browser supports it.

This plugin, as far as I can tell, adds support for native CSS transitions as opposed to manually animating the elements.